# Passing quotes and full strings to bash -c or zsh -c

Tags: bash, zsh, perl

When I am in Perl and I call `system(some_command)`, this invokes `some_command` on `/bin/sh`.  I would like it instead to run `some_command` in another shell such as `bash` or `zsh`.

One way of running commands on `zsh` or `bash` from `sh` is to call `zsh -c '<command>'`. The idea would be to pass this to `system()`, but this requires using single quotes around `<command>`.

But what if `<command>` already has quotes in it? How do I pass it to `zsh -c`? For example:

```
find . -name 'something*.txt'
```

The example above is just for illustrative purpose. Another example would be when I need to pass something with quotes to a  binary that I want to invoke from `bash` or `zsh`.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`system LIST`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), which doesn't invoke a shell.  i.e.

```
system('/bin/bash', '-c', $your_command);
```

instead of

```
system("/bin/bash -c '$your_command'");
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to pass the current environment variables to that shell?. Would `system('source', '/bin/zsh', '-c', $full_cmd')` work?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to pass the current environment to a child process.  You'd have to do something if you *didn't* want that shell to inherit your environment.

Comment: Hmm I get: `Can't exec '/bin/bash': Not a directory` when I try `system('/bin/bash', '-c', 'echo Hello world');` even though it's certainly there.

Comment: @user815423426, it works fine for me.  Does `system("/bin/bash -c 'echo Hello world'");` work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in Perl, [you're not limited to single and double quotes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

```
system q{bash -c 'echo "Hello World"'};
```